# Error "glGenBuffers is ambiguous" in Eclipse Mars

Tags: opengl, eclipse, c++

I have called a function, which is part of OpenGL correctly.

```
uint vboId;
glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);
```

This is definitely correct because the program successfully runs.

The error shown when I hover over the second line is as follows.

> 'glGenBuffers' is ambiguous '
>   Candidates are:
>   void glGenBuffers(int, unsigned int *)'

The full function is below.

```
void Loader::storeDataInVao(int position, short data[], ushort data_length) {
    uint vboId;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);
    vbos.push_back(vboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data_length * 2, &data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(position, 2, GL_SHORT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

The includes are "Loader.h", "RawModel.h" and "", two of which are my other files. However, every single one of my header files has valid header guards, defined as shown below.

```
#ifndef SRC_DISPLAY_LOADER_H_
#define SRC_DISPLAY_LOADER_H_
code here
#endif /* SRC_DISPLAY_LOADER_H_ */
```

The `glGenBuffers` is underlined red, just like any other error.

Comment: If the program compiles, and you only see that error when hovering it, it's probably a bug in the IDE's autocomplete/Intellisense-like parsing. Either way, this is a general programming issue and not something specific to game development.

Comment: @JoshPetrie, ah. Thanks for the answer. I'll submit a bug report to the Eclipse Mars developers some time, in that case.

Comment: Check your packets. Maybe there is a duplication or sth. like that. And send your full function please.

Comment: @AhmetZambak, what are packets? Apologies but I am very new to C++. Adding the function now.

Comment: Sorry, i mean included things. I thought It was java (Eclipse) :D . SO I mean those libraries like #include <GL.h> and so on. There should be a duplication.

Comment: @AhmetZambak, ah. You see, the header guards stop the header files from being included twice at a time. It really does look like a bug with Eclipse Mars.